# Wrong printf in fork

Tags: c, linux, printf, fork, semaphore

I apologize yet for my english and I hope you'll be able to understand.
So I have this problem with a printf in my program which wait the end of father and some before printf. So I have always got the father who printf all his message and then the son printf all his message whereas it should be crossed..

From what I saw, I read that I have to had fflush but it's not solve my problem.
Thx for your help.
Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <sys/sem.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>

int cpt = 0;

void fils(int *cpt){
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    (*cpt)++;
    printf("son : %d\n", *cpt);
  }
}

void pere(int *cpt){
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    (*cpt)--;
    printf("father : %d\n", *cpt);
    fflush(stdout);
  }
}

int main (int argc, char*argv[]){
  key_t key;
  int memShared;
  int *cpt = NULL;

  key = ftok(argv[0],'p');
  memShared = shmget(key, sizeof(int), IPC_CREAT|IPC_EXCL|0666);
  cpt = shmat ( memShared, cpt, 0);
  *cpt = 0;

  fflush(stdout);
  switch (fork()){
    case -1: perror("erreur de création du fils");
         exit(99);
    case  0: fils(cpt);
         exit(1);
    default: pere(cpt);
         wait(NULL);
  }
   shmctl(memShared, IPC_RMID, NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

and i always have this in the terminal

father : -1
father : -1
father : -2
son : 0
son : -1
son : 0

i though it should be crossed for example father : -1 son : 0 father : -1 ...
thanks for your help.

Comment: You say "it should be crossed", but you've implemented no mechanism to make that so. Both processes are just racing to write all their output, there's nothing in your program to make one wait for the other. If you want them to alternate their output, you have to write code to make them do that. You're also not synchronizing access to that shared memory, which is why you're getting odd output like father writing two `-1`s in a row.

Comment: You always need to keep the result of `fork` in a variable, since the father would need it for `waitpid`. See also [shm_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html) and [sem_overview(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch: Not neccessary. He's waiting for any of the exactly one child-processes to finish. That's selective enough. (We are not in the general case, where one really would have to use `waitpid`.)

Comment: @PaulGriffiths: hi and thanks for your answer. when i said "crossed" i mean i though that we never know which one of father or son will run first, so i though that or the father can run 2 iteration and printf and then the son can run 1 iteration so we can get something crossed. that is the alternate i was talking about. But yes you re right i forgot to synchronize the acces to the shared memory, i ll correct it now!

Comment: I have updated my answer to fit your question more precisely.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic race. To achieve 'son first' order, just reorder your lines in `switch`:

```
switch (fork()){
case -1: perror("erreur de création du fils");
     exit(99);
case  0: fils(cpt);
     exit(1);
default: wait(NULL); //First - wait
     pere(cpt);      //Then - print   
}
```

You have no guarantees whether such simple solution will work as you intended. What you want is to ensure that exactly one loop iteration is executed by a process until it is switched off.

If you want to ensure they go in this `ABABAB` manner, then you need another synchronization mechanism. Keep in mind, that simple semaphores will not be enough. You might want to have a pipe or a fifo queue to allow this processes to communicate. Look for functions called `pipe` or `mkfifo`. Than you can go like this:

```
for(number_of_iterations)
{
   wait for a message from the other process;
   do work on shm;
   send message to another process, allowing it to continue;
}
```

This would stimulate a notion of a token.

As for the suggestions in the comments: keeping the fork result in a variable a then waiting with `waitpid` is safer when you have more processes, as `wait` waits for the first ending process, not a particular one.

Answer (score -1):

```
chenchongyf1@chenchongyf1:~$
chenchongyf1@chenchongyf1:~$ ./wrong_printf
father : -1
son : 0
son : 1
son : 2
father : 1
father : 0
chenchongyf1@chenchongyf1:~$**
```

the program work on my computer. I mean the father's printf and son's printf indeed were crossed.

Comment: It doesn't matter. This program **may** work, but is not **guaranteed** to work. That is usually a problem with races.